# How to add enum constraint to JSchema object?

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I'm successfully building JSON schema objects in C# as [JSchema][1] objects using Json.net Schema. I'd like my schema to constrain some strings to certain values.

It seems like the enum keyword can do that, and I see that JSchema does have an enum property which seemed promising, but it's read-only. See https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchema_Enum.htm

Nothing else seems obvious from the documentation, so I'm looking for advice on how to add the enum constraint to a schema.

A little more detail:

The reason for building the JSchema this way (starting with a JSchema and building it out) is because we have a need to convert to JSON from a schema that's in a different data definition language.

The following code works:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "First": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 5
    }
  }
}
```

It yields:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "First": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 5
    }
  }
}
```

I'm looking to add

```
"enum": ["circle", "square", "triangle"]
```

as an additional constraint beyond minLength and maxLength (I know that having length constraints for am enum probably don't make inherent sense, but I'm just trying to make clear how the enum will be used.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that building up a schema bit by bit is possible using the JSchema object. I do not think it was designed for this use case.

The two ways I can see of generating a JSchema are:

1. Write the schema in JSON and then use [JSchema Load](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JSchema_Load.htm)
2. Write a C# POCO and then use [JSchemaGenerator Generate](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_Generation_JSchemaGenerator_Generate.htm) to infer the schema. I would use this option first. There is an example of this here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm

Comment: Thanks. I added more detail in the original question that clarifies things, under "A little more detail:"

Comment: @occamman your two code samples are identical. I believe the first one is supposed to be c#?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this instead:

```
"oneOf": [{"const": "circle"}, {"const": "square"}, {"const": "triangle"}]
```